# json data formatting issue while building json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Hi i am trying to convert the below json ,but extra "" is coming , can any one help to go forward,what is wrong in my code.

```
dgr.push("{value:" + per + ",label:" +"'"+ k+"'}");
```

output is getting

```
["{value:70,label:'Male'}","{value:30,label:'Female'}"]
```

Comment: Don't do this. Please, please, don't hand-construct JSON. Use an object literal (or an array literal) and pass it through `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to enclose objects between quotes. Just push them as literals.

```
dgr.push({value:per,label:k});
```

if you need to cast value or label as float or string, you can use specific typecasting

```
dgr.push({value:parseFloat(per),label:String(k)});
```